# Devise custom password changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

As the title states, I am using devise. I came upon this
[link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) that describes the process of doing this. 
I have this users controller:

```
    def update_password
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      #raise @user.to_yaml
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        # Sign in the user by passing validation in case his password changed
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        #flash[:notice] = "Password Successfully Changed"
        redirect_to settings_path
      else
        flash[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages
        render password_path
      end
    end
```

Ignore the `#raise @user.to_yaml`.
And this view:

```
        <h1>Change Password</h1>

        <%= form_for(:user, :url => { :action => 'update_password'}) do |f| %>
            <div>
                <%= f.label :current_password %>
                <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= f.label :password %>
                <%= password_field_tag :password %>
            </div>

            <div>
                <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
            </div>

          <div>
                <%= f.submit "Change Password" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

I have that view mapped to this controller method :

```
   def password
      @user = current_user
    end
```

To separate the action and the view, and my config/routes.rb is this:
`match '/password' => 'users#password', :as => 'password'`

The problem arises when I click on the "Change Password" button from the form.
This is the link it brings me to: "http://localhost:3000/assets?action=update_password&controller=users" and I get the error "Couldn't find User with id=assets"

I have no idea as to why its acting in this manner and what I'm doing wrong because I have copied what the webpage said. Has anyone had any experience with this and can aid me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 or newer you could setup your routes using the resource syntax:

```
resources :users do
  member do # These routes will apply to specific model instances
    get 'password' # /users/:id/password
    put 'update_password' # /users/:id/updated_password
  end
end
```

then you would be able to use a path helper in your `form_for` declaration

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => update_password_user_path(@user) do |form| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now when I click on the submit button I get stuck at `Missing template /password with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}.`. For some reason it requires a view, which I don't want. It seems to not be redirecting after the update_with_password.

Comment: Actually I was able to fix that. The problem now rests in the fact that every time, no matter what the input it. I get the error "Password can't be blank, Password Confirmation does not match" even though they DO match

Comment: This `<%= password_field_tag :password %>` should be `<%= f.password_field :password %>` otherwise it will not be scoped into the params for the user. If you inspect the html before making the change I think you will see what I mean.